# Unstable speed with A4964 BLDC controller

Tags: current-measurement, motor-controller

I am using an Allegro A4964 for controlling a BLDC micromotor. I have tuned the PID and all available parameters according to the documents available from Allegro.

Problem: In the control modes I have tried (open and closed speed loop) the resulting speed is varying more than I would want. I read a variation of +/- 50rpm, and I also hear this on the motor while running. The lower the RPM, the more pronounced the effect.

I'm suspecting something with the BEMF detection, but I've already tried tuning the available parameters extensively (window size, sample count, filter time), without any improvement.

I'm using Si4804 MOSFETs in M1-M3.

Any ideas what I could do to improve the accuracy?

```
// General config
configSenseMaxThresh(THRESH_100MV);
configCurrentLimit(1800, 100); // 
configSpeedFlags(DCC_DISABLED, DECEL_1);
configSpeed(SpeedControlRes::RES_0_4HZ, 0, 820);
configSpeedAccel(500, 31);
configStopOnFail(ENABLED);
configVLRvoltage(VLR_3_3V);
configGateDrive(DRIVE_11V);
configOperatingMode(SPI_ONLY);
configWakeMode(WAKE_PWM);
configPWMSense(PWM_DIRECT);
configCurrentLimitEnable(ENABLED);
configMotorMode(CLOSED_LOOP_SPEED);
configDriveMode(SINUSOIDAL);
configOvermodulation(OVM_100P);

// PWM
configPWM(PHASE3, ALIGN_CENTRE, 50000); // hz
configDither(DITHER_1600NS, DWELL_1MS, 10); // 0 steps = dither disabled
configBridge(GAIN_20, 600); // gain, dead time ns

// Gate
configGateCurrent(CUR_TURN_OFF, 0, 0); // drive turn-off current1, current2: mA, 0=switching
configGateCurrent(CUR_TURN_ON,  0, 0); // drive turn-on  current1, current2: mA, 0=switching
configGateSlew(0, 0); // ns

// Current Limiting
configCurrentLimit(1000, 100); // blank time ns, scale %

// VDS
configVDSOvervoltage(1550); // mv
configVDS(DEBOUNCE, 3150); // ns

// Startup
configStartupAlign(100, 3); // hold time ms, duty cycle percent
configStartupMotor(COAST_OFF, DESYNC_RESTART_OFF, 750, RAMP_0P);
configWindmill(DISABLED, 7, 50); // freq hz, duty cycle percent

// Ramping
const int rampStopHzx10 = freqx10 > 325 ? 325 : freqx10;
configRamp(15, 3,  rampStopHzx10, 3); // start freqx10 hz, duty, end freqx10, duty
configRampStep(10, STF_2HZ); // step time ms, step freq

configPhaseAdvance(ADV_AUTO, ADV_GAIN_4, 0); // mode, gain, degrees*10

// BEMF
configBEMFDetectWindow(560);    // degrees*100
configBEMF(SPC_6, BEMFFilterTime::BF_10MS); // samplecount, filtertime

// Commutation control
configCommSteadyPow2(0, 0);     // P, I (pow2)
configCommTransientPow2(0, 0);  // P, I (pow2)
```

[image: Schematics]

Comment: You should post the code you are controlling this with...

Comment: Thanks, I added the code used to configure the A4964. It should be reasonably readable this way- dumping the register values would be a bit hard to decode without spending a lot of time with the datasheet.

Comment: @ncore Can you be more specific about what you observe ? Speed variation in open loop but at which frequency ? Try making the motor smoothly firstly in open loop. This avoids to incriminate loop controllers.